# How do I kill processes which are running with a given executable path?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, process

I know already how I can kill all java.exe processes

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
```

But when it comes to a full executable path D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_331\bin\java.exe, how do I do ?

I'm asking because I don't want to kill other processes running on another distribution of jdk than this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`taskkill` doesn't have such an option if you check its filters with `taskkill /?`

For pure cmd, there's `wmic` that you can use:

```
wmic process where ExecutablePath="D:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_331\\bin\\java.exe" call terminate
```

Also a PowerShell solution:

```
Get-Process | ? { $_.Path -eq "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_331\bin\java.exe" } | Stop-Process
```

`?` is `Where-Object` shorthand, where you check for full path.