# What to do instead if stopping Windows service doesn't stop the process?

Tags: windows, windows-services

I'm trying to stop a Windows service with an underlying java process with command `net stop`. Sometimes the underlying process doesn't stop. I can only stop it by doing a `taskkill /f /pid`.

What can I do instead ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I kill processes which are running with a given executable path?](https://superuser.com/questions/1777714/how-do-i-kill-processes-which-are-running-with-a-given-executable-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your options are limited here.

Since your java application isn't a true Windows Service integrated with the Windows Service Control Manager, issuing a "net stop" will fail. Your java.exe will continue running and must be stopped by another method.

As you have pointed out, taskkill is one solution. When used without the "/f" parameter, taskkill should attempt to close java.exe gracefully.

Another option is to instruct your program to shut down using a custom method. For example if your program supports a web interface, you may be able to ask it to close by sending a request over the network.